# Проблема с русской кодировкой в MVC View

Tags: visual-studio, кодировка, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc

В проекте Asp.Net Core для русской Visual Studio 2017 при создании представления mvc view пропадают русские буквы. Оказывается Студия автоматически создает такие файлы в кирилической кодировке Windows 1251.
Приходится повторно сохранять такие файлы в  utf8.
Для этого используется диалог: Файл/Сохранить как, в окне разворачиваем кнопку "Сохранить с кодировкой" и выбираем utf8.
Это приходится делать каждый раз, может есть лучшее решение?

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую приучать себя к английским версиям. Попробуйте в настройках (Tools > Options > Environment > Documents) опцию "Save documents as Unicode when data cannot be saved in codepage".

Comment: И это не будет UTF-16?

Comment: Это будет UTF8 with bom